# Filemaker Full Access account password issues

Tags: security, authentication, passwords, filemaker

My FileMaker database uses a Full Access account to login into when opening the file so it doesn't prompt certain users for a password based on their active directory lookup, but for some unknown reason once in awhile lately, this full access account's password mysteriously changes and comes back with a "The account name and password you entered does not match those for any FileMaker account".  For now it seems the only way to fix this is by logging into another available Full Access account and go to File, Manage, Security and edit this account in particular with the correct expected password, and I'm positive nobody else would knowledgeably login to this account and purposely change it.  Any other reasons or glitches what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AD Authentication can be tricky. One thing to know about External Server Authentication is that it firstly checks for accounts on the local system running FileMaker Server. That means that if you run your FileMaker Server on a windows server that have usernames that match usernames on your AD-service these could interfer with each other. Some pleople tend to set up FileMaker Service on a server that also host stuff like file-sharing services. This is a bad practice for many reasons but in your case it could be conflicting accounts.

Other stuff that could be a the reason for failed authentication is if the user have a pending password change forced by a security policy.

Anyhow since external authentication does not store passwords for users in the FileMaker file I would bet your problems is outside the FileMaker environment.

Hope you find it